# How to stop my Roulette wheel from spinning for ages?

Tags: c#

I have recently created a Roulette wheel that works fine. The only problem is that it will always spin for ages (usually 10 mins+). Obviously this isn't great and I would like to know how to set a maximum that it will spin for.

```
public partial class Roulette : Form
{
    #region Variables

    int[] x = {213, 231, 250, 268, 285, 297, 310, 319, 324, 325, 326, 323, 315, 304, 291, 277, 260, 242, 223, 204, 183, 165, 147, 132, 120, 110, 102, 97, 98, 99, 104, 115, 126, 142, 158, 176, 194};
    int[] y = {152, 153, 158, 165, 174, 185, 202, 219, 236, 254, 270, 293, 307, 322, 333, 348, 355, 361, 367, 364, 362, 357, 347, 338, 321, 307, 288, 269, 254, 234, 217, 201, 185, 174, 164, 160, 155};
    string[] Number = { "0", "32", "15", "19", "4", "21", "2", "25", "17", "34", "6", "27", "13", "36", "11", "30", "8", "23", "10", "5", "24", "16", "33", "1", "20", "14", "31", "9", "22", "18", "29", "7", "28", "12", "35", "3", "26" };

    int position = 0;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int loopTimes = 0;
    int loopCount = 0;
    int ballPos = 0;
    int totalGrapes = 30;
    int currentBet = 0;
    int addEarnings;


    #endregion

    public Roulette()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Roulette_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region cboNum

        cboNum.Items.Add("0");              
        cboNum.Items.Add("32");
        cboNum.Items.Add("15");
        cboNum.Items.Add("19");
        cboNum.Items.Add("4");
        cboNum.Items.Add("21");
        cboNum.Items.Add("2");
        cboNum.Items.Add("25");
        cboNum.Items.Add("17");
        cboNum.Items.Add("34");
        cboNum.Items.Add("6");
        cboNum.Items.Add("27");
        cboNum.Items.Add("13");
        cboNum.Items.Add("36");
        cboNum.Items.Add("11");
        cboNum.Items.Add("30");
        cboNum.Items.Add("8");
        cboNum.Items.Add("23");
        cboNum.Items.Add("10");
        cboNum.Items.Add("5");
        cboNum.Items.Add("24");
        cboNum.Items.Add("16");
        cboNum.Items.Add("33");
        cboNum.Items.Add("1");
        cboNum.Items.Add("20");
        cboNum.Items.Add("14");
        cboNum.Items.Add("31");
        cboNum.Items.Add("9");
        cboNum.Items.Add("22");
        cboNum.Items.Add("18");
        cboNum.Items.Add("29");
        cboNum.Items.Add("7");
        cboNum.Items.Add("28");
        cboNum.Items.Add("12");
        cboNum.Items.Add("35");
        cboNum.Items.Add("3");
        cboNum.Items.Add("26");

        #endregion


    }

    private void picBall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Used to test the coordinates
        #region Number Input

        if (txtNumber.Text == "0")                          
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(213, 152);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "32")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(231, 153);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "15")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(250, 158);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "19")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(268, 165);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "4")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(285, 174);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "21")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(297, 185);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "2")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(310, 202);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "25")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(319, 219);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "17")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(324, 236);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "34")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(325, 254);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "6")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(326, 270);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "27")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(323, 293);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "13")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(315, 307);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "36")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(304, 322);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "11")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(291, 333);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "30")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(277, 348);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "8")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(260, 355);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "23")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(242, 361);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "10")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(223, 367);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "5")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(204, 364);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "24")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(183, 362);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "16")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(165, 357);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "33")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(147, 347);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "1")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(132, 338);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "20")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(120, 321);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "14")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(110, 307);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "31")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(102, 288);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "9")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(97, 269);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "22")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(98, 254);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "18")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(99, 234);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "29")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(104, 217);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "7")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(115, 201);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "28")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(126, 185);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "12")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(142, 175);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "35")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(158, 164);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "3")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(176, 160);
        }
        if (txtNumber.Text == "26")
        {
            picBall.Location = new Point(194, 155);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    private void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        position = 0;
        loopCount = 0;

        tmrRoll.Interval = 90;

        tmrRoll.Enabled = true;

        loopTimes = rnd.Next();
        ballPos = rnd.Next(5);

        // Used to place grapes
        #region Grapes placed

        if (txtPlaced.Text == "1")
        {
            totalGrapes--;
            currentBet = 1;
        }
        if (txtPlaced.Text == "2")
        {
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            currentBet = 2;
        }
        if (txtPlaced.Text == "3")
        {
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            currentBet = 3;
        }
        if (txtPlaced.Text == "4")
        {
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            currentBet = 4;
        }
        if (txtPlaced.Text == "5")
        {
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            totalGrapes--;
            currentBet = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            txtPlaced.Text = "Error (Bet 1-5)";
        }
        #endregion

        if (totalGrapes <= 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have run out of grapes!");
            Application.Exit();
        }


    }

    private void tmrRoll_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string guess = cboNum.Text;

        lbltotalGrapes.Text = totalGrapes.ToString();
        txtPlaced.Text = currentBet.ToString();

        picBall.Location = new Point(x[position], y[position]);


        if (position == ballPos && loopTimes == loopCount)             
        {
            tmrRoll.Enabled = false;

            int arraypos = Array.IndexOf(Number, guess);

            if (ballPos == arraypos)                                
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You guessed correctly!");





            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Try again");
                addEarnings = currentBet * 3;
                totalGrapes = totalGrapes + addEarnings;

            }
        }

        position++;

        if (position > x.Length - 1)
        {
            position = 0;
            loopCount++;
            tmrRoll.Interval += 30;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you shorten and paste relevant code only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loopTimes = rnd.Next()` returns a 32-bit signed integer that is greater than or equal to 0 and less than [MaxValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a huge number.

You want to limit the maximum number of loops, like that:

```
int loopLimit = 100; // set your limit
loopTimes = rnd.Next(loopLimit);
```

Comment: Also, please look up [loops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32dbftby.aspx), it will make your life a lot easier.